# join 5 tables on ms sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So i have a minor problem  with MS SQL , I have five tabel

```
CLIENTS , SALESMEN ,LOCATION,CARS,SALES 


Clients (ID_Client (PK), Name , Surname,Adress ,City , Phone) 

Salesmen (ID_Salesman (PK) , ID_Location (ForeignKey), Name , Surname,Adress ,City , Phone)

Location (ID_Location (PK) ,Location_Name) 

CARS (ID_Car (PK),MODEL,YEAR,Color)

Sales ( ID_Sale (PK) , ID_Klienti (FK) ,ID_Saleman (FK),ID_Location (PK) , ID_Car)
```

I Want to inner join or (join ) five of them ,i get a result of 47 rows instead  of number between 4 and 10 ,   i`ve done it but it is missing something and i cant find what  i hope you guys can help me .

this is where i got so far

```
SELECT Clients.Name , Clients.Surname,Salesname.Name,Salesname.Surname,Location.Name_Locatiob 
FROM Clients 
INNER JOIN Sales
  ON Sales.ID_Klienti = Clients.ID_Client
INNER JOIN Punetoret
  ON Salesmen.ID_Salesman = Salesmen.ID_Salesman
INNER JOIN Location
  ON Location.ID_Location = Salesman.ID_Location
INNER JOIN Veturat  
  ON  Location.ID_Location= Cars.ID_Location
```

Can somebody help my further ? I`ll  appreciate   , Thanks in Advance!

Comment: ON condition? GROUP BY?

Comment: Are you sure you are joining right tables?

Comment: What is Punetoret and Veturat you have used in your SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

Your second INNER JOIN looks suspect as the same table is referenced on both sides of the join.

```
...
INNER JOIN Punetoret
    ON Salesmen.ID_Salesman = Salesmen.ID_Salesman
...
```

Should it be

```
...
INNER JOIN Punetoret
    ON Sales.ID_Salesman = Salesmen.ID_Salesman
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are joining wrong tables. On base of your schema  should be  something like this

```
SELECT 
  Clients.Name , Clients.Surname,Salesmen.Name,
  Salesmen.Surname,Location.Location_name 
FROM Clients 
INNER JOIN Sales
  ON Sales.ID_Klienti = Clients.ID_Client
INNER JOIN Salesmen
  ON Salesmen.ID_Salesman = Clients.ID_Salesman
INNER JOIN Location
  ON Location.ID_Location = Salesman.ID_Location
INNER JOIN CARS
  ON  Cars.ID_car = Sales.ID_Car
```

(My next guess is that you have some typo in your SELECT part.)

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake translating tables but here they are like they should be and how i joint them so where i made mistake now i want to know i cant find .Thank you for your time !

> Klientet (ID_Klienti (PK), Emri , Mbiemri,Adressa ,Qyteti , Telefoni)
>
> Punetoret (ID_Puntori (PK) , ID_Lokacioni (ForeignKey), Emri , Mbiemri,Adressa ,Qyteti , Telefoni)
>
> Lokacioni (ID_Lokacioni (PK) ,Emri_Lokacionit)
>
> Veturat (ID_Veturat (PK),Modeli ,Viti,Ngjyrat)
>
> Shitjet ( ID_Shitja (PK) , ID_Klienti (FK) ,ID_Puntori (FK),ID_Lokacioni(PK) , ID_Vetura)

```
SELECT Klientet.Emri , Klientet.Mbiemri,Punetoret.Emri,
       Punetoret.Mbiemri,Lokacioni.Emri_Lokacionit ,Shitjet.Data_shitjes
FROM Klientet 
INNER JOIN Shitjet
  ON Shitjet.ID_Klienti = Klientet.ID_Klienti
INNER JOIN Punetoret
  ON Punetoret.ID_Punetori = Shitjet.ID_Punetori
INNER JOIN Lokacioni 
  ON Lokacioni.ID_Lokacioni = Punetoret.ID_Lokacioni
INNER JOIN Veturat  
  ON Lokacioni.ID_Lokacioni= Veturat.ID_Lokacioni      
WHERE Emri_Lokacionit = 'Prishtine' 
   or Emri_Lokacionit = 'Gjilan' 
   or Emri_Lokacionit = 'Mitrovice'
```

Comment: So, i'm not quite understanding.  This is a place to put answers.  Is this your answer?  If so, you need to indicate that you fixed the problem by marking the check mark.  If not, then edit this information into your question so we can better understand what you want.

Comment: Additionally, if you are not getting the output you expect, make a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) of the data and explain what you expect vs what you are getting.